# What prerequisite knowledge is needed to understand "Multiplicative group of integers modulo n"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to self teach myself [Multiplicative group of integers modulo n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) since it's a foundation in cryptography, IT Security, and Microsoft's UProve technology.

When I go to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) I am lost in a sea of symbols I don't understand, and terminology that overwhelms me.  I don't know where to begin.

What is the simplest most effective way for me to learn this group property especially in how it relates to UProve and encryption (if possible).

I would be most appreciative if someone could guide me with a set of building blocks of knowledge (terms, links, etc) that will get me to the point of comprehension.

*Please assist in tagging this question properly.*

Comment: Do you have any understanding of group theory or abstract mathematics in general?

Comment: I can recommend Burton's Elementary Number Theory.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern No I need to learn group theory and abstract mathematics (or refresh myself)

Answer (score 2):

Studying the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is pretty basic group theory. Any intro book in abstract algebra would be appropriate (I suggest Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra; it is very thorough in dealing with groups). It will also be very important to know the Euler totient function as this gives the order of the multiplicative group. Fermat's Little Theorem and Euler's Theorem will be critical parts of understanding RSA cryptography. As far as links, there are countless I could provide. It really depends on your style and "mathematics maturity"  so to speak. You'll have no problem finding a wealth of resources online

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the book $\textbf{A Computational Introduction to Number Theory  and Algebra }$ by Victor Shoup This is available online, Link: http://shoup.net/ntb/. This book contains introductory topics in Algebra and their applications to cryptography and algorithimic number theory.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a tentative guideline within Wikipedia, start with [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Then continue with [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). (Perhaps after checking [equivalence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) and [congruences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation).) At this stage you should have arrived at [your subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). You then check [Euler-Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Fermat_theorem) and the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

As was already stated, any introductory Abstract Algebra textbook will discuss this fundamental group. I recommend Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra; it is highly readable, see the relevant passages there. Also, if you care to delve a bit deeper into the structure of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{x}}=U(n),$ you could check out [this beautiful theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization) due to Gauss. In essence, it is possible to characterize exactly when (for which classes of numbers) this group will be cyclic (i.e., generated by a single element). Neat stuff.